# About Group Homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> My question is : Is it possible to find two groups such that every function from one to other is a homomorphism ?

If not how can I prove it? .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the second group is just the identity, it works.

Note: as @celtschk points out, that's the only example for the second group, as is easily shown. (See Greg Martin's remark below for proof)

Comment: The group with only the identity is known as the trivial group. Also, it should be worth mentioning that this is the *only* way to make it work.

Comment: @celtschk Yes, that's the usual term. I wanted to be clear so I spelled it out. And I agree it's the only way.

Comment: Since it's an easy proof to write down: if there exists a non-identity element $a$ in the second group, then any function that sends the identity element of the first group to $a$ is not a homomorphism.